# I took the data from the model can not see the ListView

Tags: list, model, sencha-touch, store

My code is,

```
  Ext.define('notification_list_model', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{ name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
                  { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' }]

    });

    var notification_list_store = new Ext.data.Store({    
        model: notification_list_model,
        data: [
            { firstName: 'Berkan', lastName: 'Kahya' },
            { firstName: 'Ahmet', lastName: 'Mutlu' },
            { firstName: 'Ahmet', lastName: 'Mutlu' },
            { firstName: 'Ahmet', lastName: 'Mutlu' }   
        ],           
    });

    var notification_list = new Ext.List({
        store: notification_list_store,
        itemTpl: '<div>{firstName}</div>',
        flex: 1      
    });
```

listview see data but firstName text does not print

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use [sencha documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store).

1. Model fields should come inside config.
2. In store model name should me a string

**Model**

```
Ext.define('notification_list_model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
    fields: [{ name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
              { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' }]
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
var notification_list_store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model:'notification_list_model',
    data: [
        { firstName: 'Berkan', lastName: 'Kahya' },
        { firstName: 'Ahmet', lastName: 'Mutlu' },
        { firstName: 'Ahmet', lastName: 'Mutlu' },
        { firstName: 'Ahmet', lastName: 'Mutlu' }
    ],

});
```

**List**

```
var notification_list = new Ext.List({
    store: notification_list_store,
    itemTpl: '<div>{firstName}</div>',
    flex: 1
});

Ext.Viewport.add(notification_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem,I write {name} in model but I called {firstName} in List,So

```
Ext.define('notification_list_model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
    fields: [{ name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
              { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' }]
    }
});
```

New Model:

```
  Ext.define('notification_list_model', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
             config: {
           fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
      }
});
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.. if you got the answer then you should accept it.

Comment: you understood wrongly.. your old model is perfect.. the problem is the way you created store.. post your working store code